# Obtener en una variable el resultado de pool.query

Tags: mysql, typescript, promesas, backend, async-await

Despues de varios dias de buscar informacion y no resolver el problema me dirijo aca a ver como lo soluciono....
Estoy trabajando con typescript y express en un backend con mysql (solo mysql, no mysql2 o mysql2/promise que no conozco las diferencias tampoco) y aprendiendo a trabajar con async/await anidados.

```
const userTable = async (id: number) => {
        let result = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE userId = ?', [id], (err: any, rows: any) => {
        });
        return result;
    }

    userTable(1666).then(result => console.log(result));
```

Necesito saber de que forma la variable result puede contener la informacion de err y rows que me devuelve el pool.query 
Normalmente recogia la informacion de pool.query retornando un res en la llamada:

```
public async read(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void>{
    await pool.query('SELECT * FROM user_view', (err: any, rows: any, fields: any) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.status(200).json({result: rows });
        } else {
            res.status(500).json({ err, message: "Ha ocurrido un error en su peticion" });
        }
    });
}
```

Y este me funciona a las mil maravillas pero ahora estoy haciendo una funcion que realiza mas de una consulta a la base de datos por lo que necesito obtener todo el usuario para poder realizar otra accion.
Sin mas, agradecido de las respuestas que me puedan dar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes devolver una `Promise` que resuelva con la *callback* de `query`.
En este caso, una `Promise` explícita porque no hará falta usar `await`.

```
const userTable = (id: number) =>
    new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query('SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE userId = ?', [id],
        (err: any, rows: any, fields: any) => {
            if (err) reject(err); // En caso de error, resolvemos la Promise con error
            resolve(rows); // Si no, resolvemos con el resultado
        });
    });
```

Simplemente resolvemos o rechazamos la `Promise` con el resultado que devuelve la *callback*.
Y se puede llamar normal.

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const user = await userTable(0);
        console.log(user);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})();

///////////////////

userTable(0)
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

Por último, desconozco si puedes hacerlo `async/await`. Por lo que veo, creo que no. Probablamente sea eso uno de los mayores cambios entre *mysql* y *mysql2*.

**EDIT:** Hacer una capa de abstracción genérica

```
// Una función genérica que resuelva diferentes tipos de modelos
const selectBy = <TResult>(table: string, key: string, param: number | string) =>
    new Promise<TResult[]>((resolve, reject) => {
        // Hacemos un string template para construir la query
        pool.query(`SELECT * FROM ${table} WHERE ${key} = ?`, [param],
        (err: any, rows: any, fields: any) => {
            if (err) reject(err); // En caso de error, resolvemos la Promise con error
            resolve(rows as TResult[]); // Si no, resolvemos con el resultado
        });
    });
```

De este modo podemos reaprovechar la función en diferentes escenarios.

```
interface Person {
    id: number,
    // ...
}

interface User {
    id: number,
    username: string
    // ...
}

(async () => {
    const [ user ] = await selectBy<User>(`user_table`, `username`, `rosa1`);
    const [ person ] = await selectBy<Person>(`person_table`, `personId`, user.id);

    console.log(user);
    console.log(person);
})();
```

Una vez con esto, ya se pueden sacar diferentes funciones que ahorren el paso de los parámetros `user_table` o `person_table`, por ejemplo.
La lógica interna será compartida, por lo que cualquier cambio se va a aplicar a todas las funciones delegadas, en vez de tener que ir una a una (lo cual es un foco de *bugs*).

```
const selectPerson = (id: number) => selectBy<Person>(`person_table`, `personId`, id);
const selectUser = (id: string) => selectBy<User>(`user_table`, `username`, id);

(async () => {
    const [ user ] = await selectUser('rosa1');
    const [ person ] = await selectPerson(user.id);

    console.log(user);
    console.log(person);
})();
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Acabo de probarlo @VRoxa y me funciona genial muchas gracias. Ahora le agregue otra funcion y lo probe de las dos maneras que me enviaste.

Comment: Hola, @DelvisDíaz. Procura no poner grandes líneas de código en los comentarios porque no se aprecian. De todas formas, veo que es solamente una analogía de la misma función. Te propongo dos mejoras, `Promise<any>` debería ser `Promise<TuModelo>` para tener mejor calidad en el código y más comodidad de desarrollo. También podrías aprovechar para sacar una función genérica para cualquier *SELECT* a cualquier tabla con esa misma estructura.

Comment: En otras llamadas ya estaba implementando el Promise<TuModelo> en este ejemplo no lo habia puesto para no complicar el codigo de lo que queria preguntar gracias por la propuesta. Ahora lo del SELECT generico como lo haria??? Una clase controlador abstracta y que la clase userController herede de ella???

Comment: Bueno, podrías implementar una especie de patrón *repository*, pero en tu caso necesitarías un *query builder* bastante potente. Lo que te proponía es bastante más sencillo que eso, voy a editarlo en la respuesta.

Comment: Esta genial eso.. Y por supuesto que elimina una cantidad considerable de código repetido y de posibles bugs... Te decía de una clase entera porque de esa forma podría hacer genéricas todas ls funciones del crud y llamarlas desde cada controlador... Voy a probar a ver que sale...

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de probarlo @VRoxa y me funciona genial muchas gracias. Ahora modifique algo y le agregue otra funcion, lo probe de las dos maneras que me enviaste. Estoy muy contento con el resultado.

```
const userTable = (username: string) =>
        new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
            pool.query('SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE username = ?', [username],
            (err: any, rows: any, fields: any) => {
                if (err) reject(err.message); // En caso de error, resolvemos la Promise con error
                resolve(rows); // Si no, resolvemos con el resultado
            });
        });

    const personTable = (id: number) =>
        new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
            pool.query('SELECT * FROM person_table WHERE personId = ?', [id],
            (err: any, rows: any, fields: any) => {
                if (err) reject(err.message); // En caso de error, resolvemos la Promise con error
                resolve(rows); // Si no, resolvemos con el resultado
            });
        });

        (async () => {
            try {
                const user = await userTable('rosa1');
                const person = await personTable(user[0].userId);
                await console.log(user);
                await console.log(user[0].userId);
                await console.log(person);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        })(); 

         userTable('rosa1')
            .then((rows) => personTable(rows[0].userId))
            .then((rows) => console.log(rows))
            .catch(console.error);
```

Muchisimas gracias.